# technology for connecting SAS to Oracle

Tags: oracle, sas

We're moving to SAS on the PC and users are asking what they need to connect to Oracle. I'm wondering how SAS makes the connection -- ODBC, JDBC, OCI, or something weirder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Accessing an Oracle Database from SAS on Microsoft Windows](http://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts703.pdf)

> On Microsoft Windows, you have an option to access an Oracle database from SAS. You
>   can use SAS/ACCESS Interface to Oracle, SAS/ACCESS Interface to ODBC, or
>   SAS/ACCESS Interface to OLE DB.

Answer (score 1):

Access to oracle is establsihed through the following avenues:
SAS/ACCESS Interface to Oracle, SAS/ACCESS Interface to ODBC, or
SAS/ACCESS Interface to OLE DB.

After the access is established, then you use one of the following ways to connect:
Libname statement
SQL Pass Through Facility

Very Very powerful and exciting!! You made the right choice moving to SAS. Good Luck and enjoy the ride!

Peace